# Specify function parameters in do.call

Tags: r

Lets say I have a function that fetches data from Yahoo called Yahoo.Fetch, and I run a do.call on the function, which would be:

```
do.call(merge.xts, lapply(list.of.tickers, Yahoo.Fetch))
```

The default would have `all=TRUE` in `merge.xts`, so how would I be able to specify in a do.call to have `all=FALSE`? This is just an example, but I would like to know how to change and specify parameters in apply, do.call, lapply functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add it as a named value to the existing list with `c()` which returns another list:

```
do.call(merge.xts, c( lapply(list.of.tickers, Yahoo.Fetch), all=FALSE ))
```

This is because the `c` function preserves the “list” class.

Or wrap the parameter in with an anonymous helper function:

```
do.call( function(x) merge.xts(x, all=FALSE), 
               lapply(list.of.tickers, Yahoo.Fetch))
```