# Arguments to do.call

Tags: r

Passing arguments to a function do.call. While I have read a number of related SO questions I'm still not understanding how to do so.

Specific example:

```
library(quantmod)
symbols <- c("DRN","SPY","TMF")
dataEnv <- new.env()
getSymbols(symbols, env=dataEnv)
adjClose <- do.call(merge, eapply(dataEnv, Ad))
```

Some of the rows in adjClose have "NA"s in them, which I don't want.  The "merge" function has a parameter of "all = F", that I would like to pass in as part of the do.call on the merge function. How do I do that?  Or more generally, how does one pass required and optional arguments to the do.call function?

Any advice/links/related SO questions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `adjClose <- do.call(merge, c(eapply(dataEnv, Ad), all=FALSE)) `

Comment: @eipi10 So do.call's first parameter is the function name, the second is a list of the data to be utilized and the third is/are any parameters to be used by the function?  I'm marking this as a solution, I just wanted to see if I undersood your answer

Comment: The first parameter is the function. The second parameter can be just a list, or a list and function arguments, wrapped inside `c()`. So only two parameters.

Comment: Turns out this question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262064/specify-function-parameters-in-do-call).