# Side Effects of Calling a Function in R with do.call?

Tags: r, r-caret, do.call

I'm trying to use the train function in the caret package, the code for which is [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/07069399a34f1e78454d79079acbf841ea121763/pkg/caret/R/train.default.R#L932).  Here's a very simple example of it working properly:

```
train(y ~ ., data=X, na.action=na.fail)
Error in na.fail.default(list(y = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  :
  missing values in object
```

It is expected in this case that this will fail as my data does have missing values, but the actual problem I'm trying to address is getting the same behavior, i.e. getting to this point of failure, with the following code:

```
lst <- list(form=y ~ ., data=X, na.action=na.fail)
do.call(train, lst)
Error in as.character(call_obj$na.action) :
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I can see that this is failing in the function `check_na_conflict` linked [here](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/07069399a34f1e78454d79079acbf841ea121763/pkg/caret/R/misc.R#L573), but I'm not getting why it works in the first case and not the second.My understanding of `do.call` is that it should simply convert the values in the list into arguments to pass to `train`, but evidently that is not the case?  And if not is there some other proper way to call a function like this with a list of arguments?

Edit: A simpler example is the following:

```
> f <- function(na.missing) {
              m <- match.call()
              print(paste("na.missing =", m$na.missing))
          }

> f(na.omit)
[1] "na.missing = na.omit"
> lst <- list(na.missing=na.omit)
> do.call(f, lst)
Error in paste("na.missing =", m$na.missing) :
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I was under the impression that `do.call` would simply call `f` with argument `na.missing=na.omit`, which works when calling directly.  Is there a way to get this to work properly with `do.call`?  The reason I want to use `do.call` in the first place is I want to apply the original function to a list of lists of arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Specify function parameters in do.call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262064/specify-function-parameters-in-do-call)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but no it's not the same problem.  I created a simpler example to demonstrate the core issue I'm confused about that I will add to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is because of your use of `match.call()`, rather than `do.call()`. The [purpose](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/match.call) of `match.call()` is:

> To record the call for later re-use: for example most model-fitting functions record the call as element call of the list they return. Here the default expand.dots = TRUE is appropriate.

### Without using `match.call()`

Your example does not seem to require `match.call()`, in which case, it's easier to directly use the function passed as an argument.

Let's define a simple function which takes a vector, `x`, and a function, `na_missing_fun` to index the missing values. It will return the vector without the missing values:

```r
f <- function(x, na_missing_fun) {

    x_not_na  <- x[na_missing_fun(x)] 
    return(x_not_na)

}
```

We can call this as follows:

```r
x  <- c(1,NA,3,NA,5)

f(x, na.omit) # 1 3 5
```

Similarly, using `do.call()`, we can do:

```r
do.call(f, c(list(x), na_missing_fun = na.omit)) # 1 3 5
```

If we want to apply this function to a list of vectors, we can use `lapply()`:

```r
lapply(list(x,x,x), f, na_missing_fun = na.omit)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 3 5

# [[2]]
# [1] 1 3 5

# [[3]]
# [1] 1 3 5
```

### With `match.call()`

If there is a reason that you have to use `match.call()`, you can do it but you will need to `eval()` the argument as in [line 947](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/07069399a34f1e78454d79079acbf841ea121763/pkg/caret/R/train.default.R#L947) of the `caret` code that you posted. That is because `m$na_missing_fun` is of class `name`, rather than class `function`.

```r
f <- function(x, na_missing_fun) {
    
    m  <- match.call()
    fun  <-  eval.parent(m$na_missing_fun)
    x_not_na  <- x[na_missing_fun(x)] 
    return(x_not_na)

}
```

You can then use the function `f` exactly as above:

```r
f(x, na.omit) # 1 3 5

do.call(f, c(list(x), na_missing_fun = na.omit)) # 1 3 5 
lapply(list(x,x,x), f, na_missing_fun = na.omit) # List of 3x c(1, 3, 5) as above
```