# ggplot list value changes based on printing

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a simplified version of an issue I encountered:

```
grob.list <- vector("list", length = 2)
for (i in 1:2) { 
  grob.list[[i]] <- qplot(1:5, 1:5 * (-1)^i)
}

grid.arrange(grobs = grob.list)
```

We get two of the same graph (`grob.list[[1]]` is wrong).

If we print (even invisibly) the grobs turn out correctly.

```
grob.list <- vector("list", length = 2)
for (i in 1:2) { 
  grob.list[[i]] <- qplot(1:5, 1:5 * (-1)^i)
  invisible(print(grob.list[[i]]))
}

grid.arrange(grobs = grob.list)
```

So does printing forces a ggplot object to "settle"? What does printing a ggplot object actually change to it?

Seems related to [Grid of multiple ggplot2 plots which have been made in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315611/grid-of-multiple-ggplot2-plots-which-have-been-made-in-a-for-loop) but doesn't address what printing does.

Comment: printing forces the evaluation of the argument `i`, otherwise R's lazy evaluation delays looking up a value for it until plot rendering time, at which point it's just 2. Add the line `force(i)` as the first line of `plot.g` in your original version of the question will fix it.

Comment: In this case, `lapply` actually will do the argument forcing for you: `l <- lapply(1:2,function(i) qplot(1:5, 1:5 * (-1)^i))`.

Comment: @joran can you post as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing forces the evaluation of the argument i, otherwise R's lazy evaluation delays looking up a value for it until plot rendering time, at which point it's just 2.

One option is to use `force()` in a function:

```
plot.g <- function(i) {
    force(i)
    qplot(1:5, 1:5 * (-1)^i)
}

grob.list <- vector("list", length = 2)
for (i in 1:2) { 
    grob.list[[i]] <- plot.g(i)
}

grid.arrange(grobs = grob.list)
```

...or use `lapply` which in modern versions of R will force the evaluation of the argument `i`:

```
l <- lapply(1:2,function(i) qplot(1:5, 1:5 * (-1)^i))

grid.arrange(grobs = l)
```