Making multiple ggplots at the same time
I have this data in R:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
    height = rnorm(1000, mean = 170, sd = 10),
    weight = rnorm(1000, mean = 70, sd = 15),
    country = sample(c("USA", "Canada", "UK", "Australia"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
)

I use this code to make a facet of height vs weight for each country:
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Create separate plots for each country
p1 <- ggplot(data %>% filter(country == "USA"), aes(x = height, y = weight)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    labs(title = "USA", x = "Height (cm)", y = "Weight (kg)") +
    theme_minimal()

p2 <- ggplot(data %>% filter(country == "Canada"), aes(x = height, y = weight)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    labs(title = "Canada", x = "Height (cm)", y = "Weight (kg)") +
    theme_minimal()

p3 <- ggplot(data %>% filter(country == "UK"), aes(x = height, y = weight)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    labs(title = "UK", x = "Height (cm)", y = "Weight (kg)") +
    theme_minimal()

p4 <- ggplot(data %>% filter(country == "Australia"), aes(x = height, y = weight)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    labs(title = "Australia", x = "Height (cm)", y = "Weight (kg)") +
    theme_minimal()



grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2)


Is there some in R that instead of manually making all these graphs, I can automatically make each graph with the correct titles and tile them together on the same page?
Right now I am doing this manually and its taking some time (e.g. I have 20 such graphs) - is it not possible to do this automatically?

Add + facet_wrap(~country) + theme(strip.text = element_text(hjust = 0)) at the bottom and remove the %>% filter(...) part.

If you want the countries to appear in a specific order besides alphabetical, convert country to an ordered factor. I like the forcats package for many ways to do this.

See https://r4ds.hadley.nz/layers.html#facets for more. If your variable scales change meaningfully, you might look at https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Facets.html for more options. If the charts vary in other ways, you could look at patchwork for more options about how to combine and align them.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249548/6851825

thanks everyone ... but I dont want to do this with facet_wrap ... I want to make a list of plots and then put them alltogether

Can you say more about why creating the plots separately makes more sense for your use case? Are there limitations to how you're making the charts, or how you want them to appear? What would you like a more automated process to look like?

Sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/26034177/6851825 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/15678261/6851825 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/31993704/6851825 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9315611/6851825 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/26034177/6851825

If you don't want facets, the way to go is to just write your own plotting function, and apply that to the data. E.g. like so:
my_fun <- function(data, title) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x = height, y = weight)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    labs(title = title, x = "Height (cm)", y = "Weight (kg)") +
    theme_minimal()
}
spl <- split(data, data$country)
my_plots <- purrr::map2(spl, names(spl), my_fun)
patchwork::wrap_plots(my_plots)

This generalizes; any time you find yourself writing lots of very similar code, you should probably applying a function instead.

